# jQuery Duplicate detection for list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to detect duplicate so that i can identify them and add in additional information for the user to be able to differentiate them.

But whats happening bellow is everything gets triggered as a dupe.

It's been a long day and hoping for a second pair of eyes to help out with this.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";

  $.each(["bingo a", "bingo b", "bingo c", "bingo c", "bingo d", "bingo e", "bingo e", "bingo f", "bingo g"], function(index, element) {
    var $sameValue = $(this).text(),
      $abaadd = "";


    if ($(this).next().text() === $sameValue || $(this).prev().text() === $sameValue) {
      $abaadd = ' (dupe)';
    }
    $('ul').append($('<li>' + element + $abaadd + '</li>'));


  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there HTML to this? if there isnt, you shouldnt be using $.each to iterate though your array. For example, $(this).text wont work, its not an html element.

Comment: What if you only use **$(this)** or **$(this).next()** without text() method. this should refer to current item which is your string.

Comment: All your selectors look invalid.  I'm not aware that `<bingo class="a">` would be a valid tag.

Answer (score 1):

I propose this:

```
let arr = ["bingo a", "bingo b", "bingo c", "bingo c", "bingo d", "bingo e", "bingo e", "bingo f", "bingo g"]

for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  let item = arr[i];
  let optionalValue = "";

  if (item === arr[i + 1] || item === arr[i - 1]) {
    optionalValue = "(dupe)"
  }
   $('ul').append($('<li>' + item + optionalValue + '</li>'));
}
```

Here is Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/mr_oza/5qmnewjg/2/

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes using Jquery without needing it. This should solve your problem

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";

  var arr = ["bingo a", "bingo b", "bingo c", "bingo c", "bingo d", "bingo e", "bingo e", "bingo f", "bingo g"]
  arr.forEach(function(element, index){
    var $abaadd = "";

    if (arr[index + 1] === element || arr[index-1] === element) {
      $abaadd = ' (dupe)';
    }

    $('ul').append($('<li>' + element + $abaadd + '</li>'));


  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
</ul>
```

Basically, $(this) has no property $(text), being just a string, not an html element.

Also, Taking a quick look at jQuery documentation I didn't find any .next() or .previous() on $.each, so I replaced it with a native forEach so I can access previous and next indexes to compare

Comment: Explain in a paragraph or two *why* *`"This should solve your problem"`*

Comment: Fair enough @RokoC.Buljan. Done